# no such bucket error when presigning s3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, pre-signed-url

I want to create a system that will use AWS S3 for storage. We want the files to be NOT available for the internet but we want to be able to share them. In order to do that we need to do a presign. For example take the attached file test_file.gsm. The URL is `https://bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.gsm` and the S3 path is `s3://bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.gsm`. If I try to pre-sign it with `aws s3 presign  s3://bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.gsm` I get back:

```
root@server2:~# aws s3 presign  s3://bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.gsm
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=(aws access key here)&Signature=(signature here)&Expires=1624596709
root@server2:~#
```

However the returned URL doe NOT work. I get back a NoSuchBucket error.

```
root@server2:~# curl 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com/test_file.gsm?AWSAccessKeyId=(aws access key here)&Signature=(signature here)&Expires=1624596709'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message><BucketName>bender-family.s3.amazonaws.com</BucketName><RequestId>J9PMQAXV49P011B2</RequestId><HostId>(HostID Here)</HostId></Error>root@server2:~# 
root@server2:~#
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

The gsm file is here if needed:

https://filebin.net/io13mgvf92eayq36

Comment: Try to specify the `--region <aws-region>` in your presign command. It should point to the region on which the bucket was created.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
aws s3 presign  s3://bender-family/test_file.gsm
```

(without the s3 part).